# Type circularity errors seem to be arbitrary in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

This recursive type definition is accepted by the Typescript compiler.

```js
type Recursive<T> = T & { prop: Recursive<T> };
```

I can define as many properties as I want and it will compile, but if I need all possible string properties to be recursively defined, it won't compile.

```js
type Recursive<T> = T & { [prop: string]: Recursive<T> };
```

Why is it happening? Is it possible to rewrite the second definition to make it work?

Comment: As a workaround you can go with `type Recursive<T> = T & RecursiveIndex<T>; interface RecursiveIndex<T> { [prop: string]: Recursive<T>; }`. Could you add some example how would you use it and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Another workaround: `type Recursive<T> = T & { [prop in string]: Recursive<T> };`.  This evaluates to exactly your intended definition without error, but I don't know why the error happens when you do it your way.  My search of [GitHub issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) didn't find anything, so you might consider filing as a bug.  However it helps to have a compelling use case, so you might want to talk about that more either here or in GitHub if you open an issue.  Good luck!